# How to match what's between two words with regex?

Tags: python, regex

i have this

```
begin 
    [someText]
end
```

- [someText] is dynamic
- I want to match only [someText] with a regex .
- I only want what's between these two words ( begin , end )

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you want a greedy or non-greedy match?

Comment: Which language are you using? Please post some example code ideally. How do you want to handle whitespace--do you want it included in the match?

Comment: no Mark , i only want the string inside the two words . how to get all the occurences of string between them ?

Comment: What about `begin begin end begin end end end`? Or are you saying that begin and end are never nested and always at the start of a line?

Comment: Actually yes , sometimes they are nested , and not always at the start of the line .

Answer (score 2):

Keeping all whitespace

```
re.match(r'begin(.*)end', text, re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

Ignoring whitespace before "begin" and "end":

```
re.match(r'begin\s*(.*)\s*end', text, re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

This assumes `text` always contains a match and begins with "begin".

Comment: Does not work in python3

Comment: Can you be more specific? It seems to yield what I thought you needed on Python 3.6.